# Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute ... since weaving was not enabled or did not occur

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink

I have an entity that maps two objects. After changing FetchType.EAGER to FetchType.LAZY compile application for ejection

```
    public class MessageEntity {
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity sender;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipient_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity recipient;
...
}


[EL Warning]: metadata: 2017-12-19 21:00:02.847--ServerSession(123577677)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [sender] for the entity class [class com.core.jpa.entity.MessageEntity] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2017-12-19 21:00:02.847--ServerSession(123577677)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [recipient] for the entity class [class com.core.jpa.entity.MessageEntity] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

This is my configuration of access to the database. https://pastebin.com/uKtrseUB

Comment: Can you try again with `optional=false` both in `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` and see if the warning goes away?

Comment: Did not help. Next, the same mistake.

Comment: Lazy requires weaving as the warning states. Eclipselink needs to instrument your class so it can tell when you access the relationship so it can fetch it. See http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm